# Loading data regulary from ServiceNow to Pentaho Kettle

Tags: pentaho, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, kettle, servicenow

I'm working on a BI project and I want to retrieve data from ServiceNow and load it to Pentaho Data Integration so I can record it in my data warehouse, and I want to do this regulary, in other words I want to retrieve the new records regulary from servicenow , only the new ones that haven't been loaded yet to the data warehouse, someone knows how can I acheive my goal? Help me please

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Pentaho Kettle, does it support calling RESTful web services to pull/gather data?

Answer (score 1):

The question is too vague.

1. You need to set up an ETL job that incrementally loads data. That will require you to define a timestamp or incremental key to identify which records are more recent than the ones already loaded.
2. You will need to schedule that job, e.g., using crontab and calling kitchen from the command line.

Your question pretty much translates to "please develop my ETL project". Too wide in scope.

Comment: Actually I'm working on the ETL Transformations that loads the data from a csv file into my data warehouse, the question is how to download that file automatically from servicenow to pentaho and retrieve just the new records, because in the company that I work in actually they export data in that csv file manually everytime.

Comment: 1. can you get that file via a HTTP request? there's a HTTP step for jobs to download files, which can then be processed.

Comment: 2. as to how to read only new records: you'll need to filter the incoming rows from the text file against a valid criteria to determine which rows are already in the target table and which ones are not.